# Как можно сделать макет сайта HTML?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте, как можно реализовать макет сайта как показано в след. рисунке

[image]

на все свободные места чтобы можно было написать текст или вставить объект, ширина и высота должны быть на %(процент)

Comment: ИМХО, проще всего воспользоваться таблицами.

Comment: Здавать высоту блоку в процентах уже неправильно!

Comment: @rszh, не забывайте принимать верные ответы. Для этого нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 5):

верстка:

```
    <div class="one">
      тут должно быть место для текста
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="one">
      основная чать
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="one">
      footer
    </div>
```

Стили:

```
<style type="text/css">
.one {
  width:100%;
}
.two {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.three {
  width:33.3%;
  float:left;
}
.clear {
  clear:left;
}
</style>
```

Высота по содержимому.